# Full outer joins, coalescing, indexes and views

Tags: sql-server-2012, index, view, join, coalesce

I have two tables, let's call them TableA and TableB.

```
TableA               TableB
------               ------
ID                   ID
Date                 Date
Foo                  Bar
```

Both tables have an index on their date field.
Now, I want to create a view that has a full outer join between the two tables on the Date field, to show me the `Foo` value for that date (if there is one) along with the `Bar` for that date.

```
create view vFooBar as
select isnull(a.Date, b.Date) Date, a.Foo, b.Bar
from TableA a
full outer join TableB b on a.Date = b.Date
```

Then I run a query:

```
select * from vFooBar where Date = '20141201'
```

This works... but the coalescing of `a.Date` and `b.Date` fools the compiler into not using the indexes, and I get a horrible execution plan involving table scans.

How can I create this view in such a way that querying it will still use my indexes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
select a.Date, a.Foo, b.Bar
from TableA a LEFT JOIN TableB b ON a.Date = b.Date
UNION
select b.Date, a.Foo, b.Bar
from TableB b LEFT JOIN TableA a ON a.Date = b.Date
```

Strictly speaking, the query above does not quite have the same semantics as the original full join, with respect to duplicates. A correct transformation of full join is to a left join union all anti-semi-join:

```
SELECT 
    TA.TheDate, 
    TA.Foo, 
    TB.Bar
FROM dbo.TableA AS TA
LEFT JOIN dbo.TableB AS TB 
    ON TB.TheDate = TA.TheDate
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    TB.TheDate, 
    Foo = NULL, 
    TB.Bar 
FROM dbo.TableB AS TB
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(
    SELECT NULL
    FROM dbo.TableA AS TA 
    WHERE TA.TheDate = TB.TheDate
);
```

This second rewrite will also facilitate the use of an index on `TheDate` columns.