# SQL Server: How to add a full join to two tables but have matches line up?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql, join

I am working with a system that has two databases. One for the ERP system and one for the website. Both DB's have tables for alternate codes. I am trying to write a query that will show me differences and matches between the two db's alternate code tables.

To setup my environment here is a small sample:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[alt_code_ERP](
    [UID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [item_id] [nchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [alternate_code_ERP] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[web_alt_code](
    [UID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [item_id] [nchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [web_alternate_code] [nchar](50) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[alt_code_ERP] ([UID],[item_id],[alternate_code_ERP]) VALUES (1, 'part1' , 'part1_alt')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[alt_code_ERP] ([UID],[item_id],[alternate_code_ERP]) VALUES (2, 'part2' , 'part2a_alt')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[alt_code_ERP] ([UID],[item_id],[alternate_code_ERP]) VALUES (3, 'part2' , 'part2b_alt')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[alt_code_ERP] ([UID],[item_id],[alternate_code_ERP]) VALUES (4, 'part2' , 'part2c_alt')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[alt_code_ERP] ([UID],[item_id],[alternate_code_ERP]) VALUES (5, 'part10' , 'part10_alt')
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[web_alt_code] ([UID],[item_id],[web_alternate_code]) VALUES (1, 'part1' , 'part1_alt')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[web_alt_code] ([UID],[item_id],[web_alternate_code]) VALUES (2, 'part2' , 'part2a_alt')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[web_alt_code] ([UID],[item_id],[web_alternate_code]) VALUES (3, 'part2' , 'part2d_alt')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[web_alt_code] ([UID],[item_id],[web_alternate_code]) VALUES (4, 'part8' , 'part8_alt')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[web_alt_code] ([UID],[item_id],[web_alternate_code]) VALUES (5, 'part10', 'part10b_alt')
GO
```

I want a result that will have the following:

1. List each alternate code from each table once.
2. If there are any matching alternate codes from the two tables, I want to align them side by side.
3. Any without a match in the other table to be paired with a NULL

Something that looks like the following:

item_id      alternate_code_erp   web_alternate_code

```
part1       part1_alt   part1_alt 
part2       part2a_alt  part2a_alt
part2       part2b_alt  NULL
part2       part2c_alt  NULL
part2       NULL        part2d_alt
part8       NULL        part8_alt
part10      part10_alt  NULL
part10      NULL        part10b_alt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a full outer join on the item_id and alternate_code should do the trick.

```
    SELECT COALESCE([a].[item_id], [b].[item_id]) as item_id,
       [a].[alternate_code_ERP],
       [b].[web_alternate_code]
FROM [alt_code_ERP] AS [a]
     FULL OUTER JOIN [web_alt_code] AS [b]
     ON [a].[item_id] = [b].[item_id]
    AND [a].[alternate_code_ERP] = [b].[web_alternate_code];
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a FULL OUTER JOIN.

```
SELECT ISNULL(a.item_id, w.item_id) AS item_id,
    a.alternate_code_ERP, w.web_alternate_code
FROM alt_code_erp a
FULL OUTER JOIN web_alt_code w
    ON a.item_id = w.item_id
    AND a.alternate_code_ERP = w.web_alternate_code
ORDER BY 1, ISNULL(a.alternate_code_ERP, w.web_alternate_code)
```

I added an ORDER BY in case you need it.  It's still not exactly the same but without doing some string manipulation you aren't going to get an order of item_id like you want.

Answer (score 2):

I learned a pretty cool trick of writing a FULL OUTER JOIN using  [a left join union all anti-semi-join](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/83999/8783)

```
SELECT 
    TA.item_id, 
    TA.alternate_code_ERP, 
    TB.web_alternate_code
FROM dbo.alt_code_erp AS TA
LEFT JOIN dbo.web_alt_code AS TB 
    ON TB.item_id = TA.item_id
    and TB.web_alternate_code = TA.alternate_code_ERP

UNION ALL
SELECT 
    TB.item_id, 
    Foo = NULL, 
    TB.web_alternate_code 
FROM dbo.web_alt_code AS TB
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(
    SELECT NULL
    FROM dbo.alt_code_erp AS TA 
    WHERE TA.item_id = TB.item_id
    and TB.web_alternate_code = TA.alternate_code_ERP
)
```

You get the desired output:

```
╔══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║item_id    alternate_code_ERP                                 web_alternate_code                                  ║
╠══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ part1      part1_alt                                          part1_alt                                          ║
║ part2      part2a_alt                                         part2a_alt                                         ║
║ part2      part2b_alt                                         NULL                                               ║
║ part2      part2c_alt                                         NULL                                               ║
║ part10     part10_alt                                         NULL                                               ║
║ part2      NULL                                               part2d_alt                                         ║
║ part8      NULL                                               part8_alt                                          ║
║ part10     NULL                                               part10b_alt                                        ║
╚══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

Below is the execution plan :

[image]

Bloating the table using below gives the following execution plan :

```
UPDATE STATISTICS [dbo].[alt_code_ERP] WITH ROWCOUNT = 10000000, pagecount = 10000000
UPDATE STATISTICS [dbo].[web_alt_code] WITH ROWCOUNT = 10000000, pagecount = 10000000
```

[image]

To my surprise, in my tests on a laptop with 4 logical processors, 16GB RAM with SSD, the above solution performs/scales really good when dealing with large number of rows (tried with 20,40 and 140 rows). *(Its already 12:30 AM EST .. so it might be looking good)*. Note that you dont have any Primary Key or Indexes defined in your table, so you will see sql server doing table scans.